# Как сделать загрузку заливки полигона из .geojson?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Использую модуль "Надписи на полигоне",пытаюсь загрузить данные заливки полигонов из файла .geojson из options.fillColor. Не загружает. Подскажите в чем ошибка?

var options = {

```
          labelDefaults: 'dark',
          labelLayout: textLayouts.label,
          fillColor:obj.options.fillColor,
          strokeColor: "0066ff99",
          openHintOnHover: true,
          labelTextSize: {'3_6': 12, '7_18': 14},
          cursor: 'grab',
          labelDotCursor: 'pointer',
          labelPermissibleInaccuracyOfVisibility: 4

        };

        geoJson.features.forEach(function (obj) {
            obj.options = options;
            return obj;

        });
```

Comment: Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый код с возникающими трудностями на jsfiddle.net.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nikodim1986/ev9cLs35/6/ только не получается почему то файл открыть здесь.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере кода есть несколько ошибок.

- API-ключ Яндекс не должен быть заключён в угловые скобки при инициализации скрипта. **&apikey=624a...0e92&** , а не **&<apikey=624a...0e92>&**
- Подключать любые внешние скрипты необходимо, используя защищённый протокол https, иначе загрузка не будет выполнена. **<script src="https://yandex.st/jquery...**
- Обрабатывая опции в цикле **forEach** вы заменяете элемент **options** единым объектом, игнорируя особенности каждого полигона, хотя у ваших features есть и **options**, и **properties**.
  Если присвоение опций внести в этот цикл, оригинальные значения затираться не будут и цвета будут из опций. А если в цикл добавить замену опций параметрами, то можно использовать другой источник цвета (у вас в файле они разные).

$.getJSON('https://raw....').done(function (geoJson) {

```
geoJson.features.forEach(function (obj) {
        obj.options.labelDefaults = 'dark',
        obj.options.labelLayout = textLayouts.label,
        obj.options.strokeColor = "0066ff99",
        obj.options.openHintOnHover = true,
        obj.options.labelTextSize = {'3_6': 12,'7_18': 14},
        obj.options.cursor = 'grab',
        obj.options.labelDotCursor = 'pointer',
        obj.options.labelPermissibleInaccuracyOfVisibility = 4, 
        obj.options.fillColor = obj.properties.fill
        //obj.options = options;
        return obj;
    });
```

Заливка из options: https://jsfiddle.net/d4u83qp5/

Заливка из properties: https://jsfiddle.net/zsa8kq5o/